# Getting Computer Specs with MS-DOS

Tags: ms-dos, windows-98

I have a laptop here that's running good old Windows 98. Instead of command prompt it has MS-DOS. Is there an equivalent to the **systeminfo** command for MS-DOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new text file in notepad with the extension .nfo, open the file it will say it is broken ignore that, it will tell you everything about the machine.

Answer (score 4):

For MS-DOS [`msd`](http://www.computerhope.com/msdhlp.htm), but it is not the full equivalent.

Comment: I agree `msd.exe` is the way to go.  It isn't the full equivalent, but it does show essentially everything that MS-DOS can see and utilize.

Answer (score 2):

A great system inventory tool for DOS is [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com/download.html). There is also a Windows version. At one time it was a commercial program, but is now freeware.